# TypeError: load() missing 1 required positional argument: 'f'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I am using MacPro M1 Pro chip

Error message

"Attempting to deserialize object on a CUDA device but torch.cuda.is_available() is False. If you are running on a CPU-only machine, please use torch.load with map_location=torch.device('cpu') to map your storages to the CPU."

How to solve this issue/

What change is to be made to help me to execute the following command:
python pc_certification.py --model resnetv2_50x1_bit_distilled_cutout2_128  --dataset imagenette --num_img -1  --num_mask 6 --patch_size 32

```
import torch
import torch.backends.cudnn as cudnn

import numpy as np 
import os 
import argparse
import time
from tqdm import tqdm
import joblib

from utils.setup import get_model,get_data_loader
from utils.defense import gen_mask_set,double_masking_precomputed,certify_precomputed


    

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--model_dir",default='checkpoints',type=str,help="directory of checkpoints")
parser.add_argument('--data_dir', default='data', type=str,help="directory of data")
parser.add_argument('--dataset', default='imagenette',type=str,choices=('imagenette','imagenet','cifar','cifar100','svhn','flower102'),help="dataset")
parser.add_argument("--model",default='vit_base_patch16_224',type=str,help="model name")
parser.add_argument("--num_img",default=-1,type=int,help="number of randomly selected images for this experiment (-1: using the all images)")
parser.add_argument("--mask_stride",default=-1,type=int,help="mask stride s (square patch; conflict with num_mask)")
parser.add_argument("--num_mask",default=-1,type=int,help="number of mask in one dimension (square patch; conflict with mask_stride)")
parser.add_argument("--patch_size",default=32,type=int,help="size of the adversarial patch (square patch)")
parser.add_argument("--pa",default=-1,type=int,help="size of the adversarial patch (first axis; for rectangle patch)")
parser.add_argument("--pb",default=-1,type=int,help="size of the adversarial patch (second axis; for rectangle patch)")
parser.add_argument("--dump_dir",default='dump',type=str,help='directory to dump two-mask predictions')
parser.add_argument("--override",action='store_true',help='override dumped file')

args = parser.parse_args()
DATASET = args.dataset
MODEL_DIR = os.path.join('.',args.model_dir)
DATA_DIR = os.path.join(args.data_dir,DATASET)
DUMP_DIR = os.path.join('.',args.dump_dir)
if not os.path.exists(DUMP_DIR):
    os.mkdir(DUMP_DIR)

MODEL_NAME = args.model
NUM_IMG = args.num_img

#get model and data loader
model = get_model(MODEL_NAME,DATASET,MODEL_DIR)
val_loader,NUM_IMG,ds_config = get_data_loader(DATASET,DATA_DIR,model,batch_size=16,num_img=NUM_IMG,train=False)

device = 'cuda' 
model = model.to(device)
model.eval()
cudnn.benchmark = True

# generate the mask set
mask_list,MASK_SIZE,MASK_STRIDE = gen_mask_set(args,ds_config)

# the computation of two-mask predictions is expensive; will dump (or resue the dumped) two-mask predictions.
SUFFIX = '_two_mask_{}_{}_m{}_s{}_{}.z'.format(DATASET,MODEL_NAME,MASK_SIZE,MASK_STRIDE,NUM_IMG)
if not args.override and os.path.exists(os.path.join(DUMP_DIR,'prediction_map_list'+SUFFIX)):
    print('loading two-mask predictions')
    prediction_map_list = joblib.load(os.path.join(DUMP_DIR,'prediction_map_list'+SUFFIX))
    orig_prediction_list = joblib.load(os.path.join(DUMP_DIR,'orig_prediction_list_{}_{}_{}.z'.format(DATASET,MODEL_NAME,NUM_IMG)))
    label_list = joblib.load(os.path.join(DUMP_DIR,'label_list_{}_{}_{}.z'.format(DATASET,MODEL_NAME,NUM_IMG)))
else:
    print('computing two-mask predictions')
    prediction_map_list = []
    confidence_map_list = []
    label_list = []
    orig_prediction_list = []
    for data,labels in tqdm(val_loader):
        data=data.to(device)
        labels = labels.numpy()
        num_img = data.shape[0]
        num_mask = len(mask_list)

        #two-mask predictions
        prediction_map = np.zeros([num_img,num_mask,num_mask],dtype=int)
        confidence_map = np.zeros([num_img,num_mask,num_mask])        
        for i,mask in enumerate(mask_list):
            for j in range(i,num_mask):
                mask2 = mask_list[j]
                masked_output = model(torch.where(torch.logical_and(mask,mask2),data,torch.tensor(0.).cuda()))
                masked_output = torch.nn.functional.softmax(masked_output,dim=1)
                masked_conf, masked_pred = masked_output.max(1)
                masked_conf = masked_conf.detach().cpu().numpy()
                confidence_map[:,i,j] = masked_conf
                masked_pred = masked_pred.detach().cpu().numpy()
                prediction_map[:,i,j] = masked_pred
                
        #vanilla predictions
        clean_output = model(data)
        clean_conf, clean_pred = clean_output.max(1)  
        clean_pred = clean_pred.detach().cpu().numpy()
        orig_prediction_list.append(clean_pred)
        prediction_map_list.append(prediction_map)
        confidence_map_list.append(confidence_map)
        label_list.append(labels)
    
    prediction_map_list = np.concatenate(prediction_map_list)
    confidence_map_list = np.concatenate(confidence_map_list)
    orig_prediction_list = np.concatenate(orig_prediction_list)
    label_list = np.concatenate(label_list)

    joblib.dump(confidence_map_list,os.path.join(DUMP_DIR,'confidence_map_list'+SUFFIX))
    joblib.dump(prediction_map_list,os.path.join(DUMP_DIR,'prediction_map_list'+SUFFIX))
    joblib.dump(orig_prediction_list,os.path.join(DUMP_DIR,'orig_prediction_list_{}_{}_{}.z'.format(DATASET,MODEL_NAME,NUM_IMG)))
    joblib.dump(label_list,os.path.join(DUMP_DIR,'label_list_{}_{}_{}.z'.format(DATASET,MODEL_NAME,NUM_IMG)))


clean_corr = 0
robust = 0
orig_corr = 0
for i,(prediction_map,label,orig_pred) in enumerate(zip(prediction_map_list,label_list,orig_prediction_list)):
    prediction_map = prediction_map + prediction_map.T - np.diag(np.diag(prediction_map)) #generate a symmetric matrix from a triangle matrix
    robust += certify_precomputed(prediction_map,label)
    clean_corr += double_masking_precomputed(prediction_map) == label
    orig_corr += orig_pred == label

print("------------------------------")
print("Certified robust accuracy:",robust/NUM_IMG)
print("Clean accuracy with defense:",clean_corr/NUM_IMG)
print("Clean accuracy without defense:",orig_corr/NUM_IMG)
```

Comment: Please post the full error message, as text

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the error is telling you you're trying to using CUDA but do not have a device available (e.g., a GPU).

You said you're using a MacBook, I think it's reasonable to assume it does not have an NVIDIA Card, right?

If you want to execute it on CPU you need to modify these lines (and maybe more):

```
device = 'cuda' 
model = model.to(device)
```

The device should be `cpu`.

Otherwise, if you want to use CUDA (and you have a GPU card available), then you need to review your setup and double check that you have installed the CUDA toolkit appropriately.

Comment: I tried to do this but it didn't fix the issue

Comment: It seems like the answer is posted on your question:

If you are running on a CPU-only machine, please use torch.load with map_location=torch.device('cpu') to map your storages to the CPU."

You probably need to modify other parts of the code, like the the ones in utils.setup.

Comment: Also, there's not a lot more I can do without access to the whole code, as it seems the problem persists is in another code file, e.g., where it's calling 'torch.load'.